# Кнопка на сайте

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите как понять где id кнопки?
кнопка код:

```html
class="btn button button-3d editable block_148033 item item-field_button_text item-option_1 item-int_862618"
```

Comment: Если Вы в инспекторе не видите атрибут id, то его нет, он не обязательно должен быть.

Comment: спасибо большое))